# Create list of favorites in ApplicationUser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

On my website, I am using a custom ApplicationUser. I want to store favorites into a field on the ApplicationUser, but I'm having issues doing so.

I have a model like so:

```
public class Score
{
    public int ScoreId{ get; set; }
}
```

This model is created with a DBContext:

```
public class SongsContext : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<Score> Scores { get; set; }
}
```

and then seeded with a DbContextInitializer.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public List<Scores> FavoriteScores { get; set; }
}
```

Whenever I try to add this to my database using EF migrations, all that happens is it wants to generate tables of all my models that normally get created using my DbContext (but doesn't actually add a column for FavoriteScores in my Users table). EF also won't let me store a list of ints that reference the ScoreID's without creating a new class with the sole purpose of holding ints.

What would be the best way to reference a list of Scores with my ApplicationUser object?

Comment: One option is to have your SongsContext inherit from IdentityDbContext. If you don't want to do that, then you can create a simple Scores class in the IdentityDbContext and reference it there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure a many to one relationship on your Score entity. You can do that by adding a reference to the Application user Id to your Score class.

```
public class Score
{
    public int ScoreId{ get; set; }
    public int ApplicationUserId{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser{ get; set; }
}
```

You can read more about many to one relationships here http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: ApplicationUser is in a different context though. Also, since his keys follow convention (ScoreId) you don't need annotations to define the relationship. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx